# Завершить службы циклом

Tags: c#, windows-service

Можно ли остановить службы циклом?
У меня есть список служб, занёс их в List

```
 List<string> name = new List<string> { "AdobeARMservice", "RemoteRegistry", "TermService", "Messenger", "SSDPSRV", "Telnet",
             "mnmsrvc", "Schedule", "seclogon", "SessionEnv", "bthserv",
             "WinRM", "SCardSvr", "WbioSrvc", "SCPolicySvc","RtkBleServ"};
```

Как-то так попытался:

```
 foreach (ServiceController service in ServiceController.GetServices())
            {
                if (service.ServiceName == name[15])
                {
                    service.Stop();
                    Console.WriteLine("Остановлен");
                }
            }
```

Или как можно по другому?

Решил вопрос:

на Linq!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.ServiceProcess;

namespace ConsoleApplication25 {
    class Program {
        static List<string> services = new List<string> {
            "AdobeARMService", "RemoteRegistry", "TermService", "Messenger", "SSDPSRV"
        };
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Run());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        static void Run() {
            while (true) {
                var temp = ServiceController.GetServices().Where(s => services.Contains(s.ServiceName)).ToList();
                temp.ForEach(t => {
                    try {
                        t.Stop();
                    }
                    catch { }
                });
                Thread.Sleep(500);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

без Linq

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.ServiceProcess;

namespace ConsoleApplication25 {
    class Program {
        static List<string> services = new List<string> {
            "AdobeARMService", "RemoteRegistry", "TermService", "Messenger", "SSDPSRV"
        };
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            new Thread(Run) { IsBackground = true }.Start();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        static void Run() {
            while (true) {
                List<ServiceController> temp = new List<ServiceController>();
                foreach (var s in ServiceController.GetServices()) {
                    if (services.Contains(s.ServiceName)) {
                        temp.Add(s);
                    }
                }
                foreach (var s in temp) {
                    try {
                        s.Stop();
                    }
                    catch { }
                }
                Thread.Sleep(500);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать так, что бы конструкторы служб принимали в качестве аргумента `CancellationToken` и в самих службах вызывать метод `ThrowIfCancellationRequested()`, время от времени.

Тогда можно будет вызвать из основного кода `CancellationTokenSource.Cancel` и службы массово завершаться.

Comment: Можете пример привести пожалуйста